# What is the meaning of calculating sine of a number?

Tags: trigonometry, education, math-history

When we calculate sine/cos/tan etc. of a number what exactly are we doing in terms of elementary mathematical concept, please try to explain in an intuitive and theoretical manner and as much as possible explain in the most basic mathematical way.

Comment: Do you have any idea what sin / cos / tan means? If yes, can you write it down so that we know better how to help you?

Comment: Do you know what the sine means in the context of triangles, or the unit circle?

Comment: We calculate the sine of an angle. This is an important distinction. Best of luck with your studies in trigonometry.

Comment: Would you accept that these are just functions just as $\sqrt x$ ?

Comment: @PeterFranek i know whatever the colg and school books teach

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici why does everyone insist on a mathematical explanation for a mathematical entity.

Comment: @J.W.Perry what are you talking about i do not understand.

Comment: @T.Bongers no please do explain.

Comment: @EvilWarrior Sorry I missed your comment (busy). If you are still looking for further information, I may put something up. Before that, read this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Right-angled_triangle_definitions), in particular the "right angled triangle definitions." It is what I had in mind (mostly not completely) with respect to what we are doing in terms of an "elementary mathematical concept." Report back and tell me if that section of that particular wiki clarifies why I made that last comment. Also mention your current understanding of trigonometry.

Comment: @J.W.Perry i have read your reference and i know this definition, i am interested in the kind of explanation which was given by alex.jordan below, thank you for your time, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a unit-radius circle centered at the origin, place yourself at $(1,0)$. Now to calculate $\sin(x)$ for the given number $x$, move counter-clockwise around the circle until you have traveled a distance $x$. Wherever you land, the $y$-coordinate is $\sin(x)$. And the $x$-coordinate is $\cos(x)$. The slope of the line connecting the origin to wherever you are is $\tan(x)$.

Comment: i have never heard of this explanation, can you please explain further, or can you tell me of a resource/book which explains in this manner.

Comment: @EvilWarrior: This is a very standard treatment of the trigonometric functions; you can find it in almost any book with "precalculus" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the whole story, anyhow you could have a "aha!" moment.

I refer to G. A. Jennings $\,$ *Modern Geometry with Applications* $\,$ (1994), pp. 25-26, paraphrasing the text.

To solve practical problems, initially they drew and measured scale models of triangles; then someone realized that it could be useful to have a table of triangles and their dimensions, putting in the table **the dimensions of the right triangles with the hypotenuse of length one**. *Sines* and *cosines* are the lengths of the legs of those right triangles. Then the dimensions of any right triangle can be obtained by similarity multiplying the table entries by a suitable factor.
It is enough to consider only right triangles because a generic triangle can be seen as the sum or the difference of two right triangles.

Summing up, trigonometric tables are a substitute for scale drawings.